# Display data from mysql table inside a <span>

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to display data from a mysql table inside a  which is inside a  but i get a syntax error in the echos where i start to display the $data and i can't really understand why , here's the code :

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($req)) {
  echo'<div class="row">';
    echo'<input type="radio" name="expand">';
    echo '<span class="cell primary" data-label="Date">'$data['date']'</span>';
   echo'<span class="cell" data-label="Titre"> <a href="read_msg.php?id_msg_usr='$data['id_msg_usr']'"> </span>';
     echo'<span class="cell" data-label="Fromm">'stripslashes(htmlentities(trim($data['fromm'])))'</span>';
  echo'</div>';
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: and the syntax error is .... ?

Comment: <span class="cell primary" data-label="Date">$data['date']</span> insert ' to top and finish and insert } to after </div>';

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Thanks for the advices i will try to read and learn more about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put dots in so many places...

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($req)) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="expand">';
    echo '<span class="cell primary" data-label="Date">'.$data['date'].'</span>';
    echo '<span class="cell" data-label="Titre"> <a href="read_msg.php?id_msg_usr='.$data['id_msg_usr'].'"> </span>';
    echo '<span class="cell" data-label="Fromm">'.stripslashes(htmlentities(trim($data['fromm']))).'</span>';
    echo'</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much , it works fine now ! I'm still very new to this and i'm trying to learn as much as i can from examples but sometimes i hit a wall like this :)

Comment: @Silversprint, if this answer helped you, you may accept it by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some concatenation dots (`.`) and a closing parenthesis `)`.
Use [php heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to avoid this kind of errors, i.e.:

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($req)) {
$fromm = stripslashes(htmlentities(trim($data['fromm'])));
$id_msg_usr = $data['id_msg_usr'];
echo <<< LOL
<div class="row">
   <input type="radio" name="expand">
   <span class="cell primary" data-label="Date">{$fromm}</span>
   <span class="cell" data-label="Fromm">{$id_msg_usr}</span>
</div>
LOL;
}
```

---

PS: is `fromm` correct or should it be `from` only?